# magento - add to cart extension?

Tags: php, magento-1.9.1

we have tried multiple add to cart extensions but no i found like i have a requirement. i am wanted to get name of add to cart extension. in which we can add item into cart from the product list page. and also i have option like add or remove quantity from the same page.

also i have shared the link of website where this type of extension used.
[1]https://www.grubmarket.com/home

Comment: Are you trying to implement Ajax dd to cart?

Answer (score 0):

there are several extension which are quit useful.

https://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/ajax-cart-pro.html

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ajaxcart-3-15606.html

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ajax-cart-ajax-add-to-cart-extension-by-mageworld.html

if you are looking for free extension then go to 
[ww.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/](http://ww.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/) 
and search for `Ajax Cart` then refine you result for free.

[Free ajax cart](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?id=&s=7&pl=0&eb=0&hp=0&q=Ajax%20Cart&t=1&p=1)

I think this might be helpful to you.